# Xfce desktop wallpaper goes behind pannel

Tags: xfce

I have tried using Xfce, and set it up with a single pannel at the bottom of the screen. I got it by simply removing the pannel that was previously at the bottom and moving the pannel at the top down *(after starting with the default Xfce layout)*.

My issue is that when I try to set a desktop wallpaper with an option like "Scaled" or "Stretched", the bottom of the picture goes behind the pannel. How can I set it so that it only scales to fill the visible part of the desktop without the image going behind the opaque pannel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible. The panel is displayed by xfce4-panel. The wallpaper is displayed by xfdesktop. Due to xfce's modular nature, they do not directly "know" of each other. Not even [xfdesktop's advanced configuration docs](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfdesktop/advanced) mention an appropriate feature.

I suggest you use an image editor of your choice (GIMP has an extensive GUI), scale your wallpaper to the size of your screen but with a border where the panel will be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, editing the image(s) is not feasible *(unless I had a script to systemically pad each of the images)*, as I wanted to have it periodically switch between a large number of images. Is there any “hack solution” I could use to manually set the space that the images scale to?

Comment: You can use Imagemagick for padding each of the images: `convert input.jpg -resize 1920x1040 -gravity north -background black -extent 1920x1080 output.jpg` will rescale to 1040 pixels height plus 40 pixels border for the space behind the panel. You may append `^` (fill space, keeping aspect ratio) or `!` (do not keep aspect ratio) to the size given to resize command. Take care not to overwrite your original files! Alternatively, you could use xfce4-panel's option to hide the panel whenever the mouse pointer is not near it.